# How to set Udpsrc for GStreamer to a remote UDP - streaming from a GoPro

Tags: udp, streaming, gstreamer, gopro

Hej!

I'm trying to set up the following:

I have a GoPro Session 5 which streams from udp://10.5.5.9:8554
I have a raspberry pi 3 that is connected to the GoPro's wifi hotspot
I'd like to stream from the GoPro via the rpi over 4g to a Gstreamer viewer (in this case QGroundControl) on another computer with a static ip.

I can get this working by means of this tool:

https://github.com/KonradIT/gopro-py-api

and this command:

```
ffmpeg -f mpegts -i udp://10.5.5.9:8554 -map 0:0 -c copy -f rtp 
udp://94.234.203.109:5000
```

Now I'd like to see if I can get better performance using Gstreamer.

I'm trying the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

gst-launch-1.0 -v \
rtpbin name=rtpbin \
udpsrc uri=udp://10.5.5.9:8554 \
! queue \
! avenc_h264_omx bitrate=500000 \
! "video/x-h264,profile=high" \
! h264parse \
! queue max-size-bytes=10000000 \
! rtph264pay pt=96 config-interval=1 \
! rtpbin.send_rtp_sink_0 rtpbin.send_rtp_src_0 \
! udpsink port=5000 host=94.234.203.109 ts-offset=0 name=vrtpsink
rtpbin.send_rtcp_src_0 \
! rtpbin.recv_rtcp_sink_0
```

And get this error:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
ERROR: Pipeline doesn't want to pause.
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc0: Could not get/set settings from/on resource.
Additional debug info:
gstudpsrc.c(1548): gst_udpsrc_open (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc0: bind failed: Error binding to address: Cannot assign requested address
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

Can someone spare me some knowledge? Thanks!